Approaches to a `Render` function in functional reactive programming
You have a signal function PointlessButton which inhabits Signal (Maybe Unit) -> ? that represents a button that does nothing, and a rendering function, Render that inhabits ? -> Signal (ScreenDimensions -> RGB), where ScreenDimensions = Nat × Nat and RGB = Nat × Nat × Nat, that takes the entire FRP circuit and maps each pixel of the screen to an RGB value.  PointlessButton is associated to two possible renderings corresponding to when it is clicked or not, which are inhabitants of Nat × Nat -> Maybe RGB that return None when given pixels over which the button is not defined.
My question is, what exactly is the relationship between PointlessButton and Render? Or more precisely,

What should be in charge of passing the two renderings to Render, so that it can make use of them?
What datatype is passed to Render, so that it knows which of these is the one that should be used at a particular moment in time?

My work on the question in the comments. Hints, references, comments highly appreciated!

Here are my thoughts on this so far. It seems that one possible implementation of Render could take a list of all possible renderings of all components on a page, i.e., a list of inhabitants of Nat × Nat -> Maybe RGB, along with a background function, Nat × Nat -> RGB, and produce its result by composing the relevant functions together with the background function to produce a rendering. With this method, the renderings of PointlessButton are either hard-coded into Render or we assume some other initialization step that passes the list to Render

But with this implementation, I'm not sure what should be passed to Render in order for it to choose exactly which renderings Nat × Nat -> Maybe RGB are the ones to compose with the background function in order to create the final rendering. One possibility I thought of was maybe some sort of binary vector? The length of the vector would be given by the number of components on a page and the number of possible renderings of each component. So if a page only has PointlessButton on it, we'd pass the vector [1, 0] or [0, 1] to Render to make the choice
